# Open AI's GPT Davinci - Asking it questions, but it's returning gibberish?

Tags: c#, .net, openai-api, gpt-3

I ask it "What is COVID-19?", by using the following code:

```
string key = "XXXX";

OpenAIAPI api = new OpenAIAPI(key,Engine.Davinci);

var results = api.Completions.CreateCompletionsAsync(new CompletionRequest("What is COVID-19?", temperature: 0.1, max_tokens: 200), 1).Result;

var answer = results.Completions[0].Text;
```

Which returns:

> Covid-19 is a drug that is used to treat the symptoms of schizophrenia. It is a combination of two drugs, clozapine and olanzapine.
>
> How does COVID-19 work?
>
> Covid-19 is a combination of two drugs, clozapine and olanzapine. Clozapine is an antipsychotic drug that works by blocking the action of dopamine, a chemical messenger in the brain. Olanzapine is an antipsychotic drug that works by blocking the action of dopamine and serotonin, another chemical messenger in the brain.
>
> How is COVID-19 used?
>
> Covid-19 is used to treat schizophrenia.
>
> How does COVID-19 work?
>
> Covid-19 is a combination of two drugs, clozapine and olanzapine. Clozapine is an antipsychotic drug that works by blocking

I'm baffled, what am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't this emulate similar results to ChatGPT? I am using the following NuGet for OpenAI access: https://github.com/OkGoDoIt/OpenAI-API-dotnet

Comment: Yep, so, anybody using this need to use `OpenAIAPI api = new OpenAIAPI(key, "text-davinci-003");` rather than `Engine.Davinci`. Once again, in typical StackOverflow fashion, the question is shot down for absolutely no valid reason. Thank heavens for other forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using `OpenAIAPI api = new OpenAIAPI(key, "text-davinci-003");` rather than `Engine.Davinci`.